# How to chain Internet Connection Sharing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ics

Imagine this setup:

```
- internet - [pc1] - [pc2] - [pc3]
```

pc1, pc2, pc3 each have two network cards and run Windows 10. pc1 has Internet Connection Sharing enabled, so pc2 connects to the internet through it. How do I set up Internet Connection Sharing on pc2 as well, so pc3 gets connected to internet through pc2? Problem is that Windows 10 seems to use a hardcoded network (192.168.137.0/24) for ICS. I suppose I would need to set up pc2 to use another network, to avoid IP conflicts. How do I do that?

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and get a switch. A 4-port 100 MBit/s switch is only a few bucks.

Comment: @DanielB Even better would be to plug the internet cable into a router with ethernet ports and hook up all 3 pcs, I know. But it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set up the second ICS instance at all. On PC 2, *bridge* both network cards so that the computer begins acting as an Ethernet switch. (You can do this in Windows' `ncpa.cpl` by selecting both ports and choosing "Bridge Connections" from the right-click menu.) That way devices on both "sides" will belong to the same subnet with no extra configuration.

(Of course it would be better to connect a *real* switch to PC 1, and chain both PC 2 and PC 3 directly off that.)

Comment: What would be the network setup on pc3 then? Just like on pc2? pc1 will be the default gateway after it gets an IP address from pc1?

Comment: Just regular DHCP.

Comment: Note: You might not need ICS at all if you already have _another_ router with DHCP in front of PC1. In that case you could just use bridging on all computers.

Comment: first attempt to get an IP on pc3 after bridging the NICs on pc2 failed. I assume I might need to check firewall on pc2 and add explicit rules to allow DHCP traffic (UDP ports 67,68)?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary with the normal Windows firewall. (Third-party ones? Maybe.) I'd first install Wireshark and investigate. When PC3 sends the DHCP query, does PC1 see it? (Does PC2 see it on both interfaces?) Likewise with responses.

Comment: I will get a sniffer installed and see